# Java DatagramSocket bind to two consecutive open ports

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port

I'm trying to initialize two DatagramSockets on adjacent ports as such:

```
int iport = 5000;
DatagramSocket sock1 = new DatagramSocket(iport);
DatagramSocket sock2 = new DatagramSocket(iport + 1);
```

However, this fails if port 5000 or 5001 is unavailable. I don't care what ports I bind to, as long as they satisfy the condition that `sock1.getPort() + 1 == sock2.getPort()`. Is there an easy way to find two adjacent ports without iterating over all available ports and trying to bind to each of them until I find two that work?

Comment: You probably want to choose ports not already reserved for other protocols: _[Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)_.

Comment: Why? The requirement is completely impractical. And if you don't care what they are, why do you care that they're adjacent? Why do you need two sockets at all?

Comment: I'm communicating with a server that for whatever reason sends responses to the port one higher than the port I sent from. Doesn't make a whole lot of sense but I don't have access to the server code...

Answer (score 0):

`DatagramSocket()` let OS choose a free port for you, while `DatagramSocket(port)` try to get a specific port.

So you can do it like this:

```
DatagramSocket sock1 = null;
DatagramSocket sock2 = null;

while (sock2 == null) {
    sock1 = new DatagramSocket();
    try {
        sock2 = new DatagramSocket(sock1.getLocalPort() + 1);
    } catch (java.net.BindException ex) {
        sock1.close();
    }
}
```

The `while` loop is here because there is a very little chance that sock1's port + 1 has already be binded.